# Why do teenage girls "fall in love" with idols?

Tags: love

Why do teenage girls "fall in love" with idols they never met?

This behaviour is much more uncommon (if it happens at all) among teenage boys (At least in my experience. I also did a quick survey among around a dozen adults, half men, half women, none of the men recalled something like this from their teens, most of the women did.).

Comment: Do teenagers have any real idea what love is in this context? They may lust over them just as 80s teenage boys lusted over Pamela Anderson or they may just be infatuated, but love? I think on this basis, the question may solicit more opinion than fact